# Does ruby have an array sum method for boolean values?

Tags: ruby, boolean-logic

Ruby allows you to do

```
[5,5,5].sum
=> 15
```

Is there anything for doing boolean arithmetic on an array like

```
[true, true, true].sum
=> true
[true, false, true].sum
=> false
```

Comment: Currently using ![true,false,true].include?(false) but that's not great to read.

Comment: `[5,5,5].sum` is Rails (ActiveSupport), not plain Ruby.

Comment: Another way (though `all?` is best): `[true, true, true].reduce(:&)`.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
[true, true, true].all?
```

will return true.

```
[true, false, true].all?
```

will return false.

Furthermore, if you want to boolean OR the values:

```
[true, false, true].any?
```

returns true.